# Synchronizing two threads with a third where one of the first two can fail

Tags: c++, multithreading, mutex, atomic, thread-local

1. I am having problems with reliable thread synchronization. Imagine you are having two sensor threads running in parallel pinned to the different cores `thread_local` storage. They are reading the values from the sensors and performing some calculations. When they finish the execution they **propose** a certain value to the third thread and then they are put to sleep for the remaining time. This is happening inside of infinite while loop so the threads are woken up again in the next iteration and performing the same operation again.

The problem with synchronization happens because the third thread is running at a much faster pace without sleep time. I want this thread to check incoming requests of both threads just once per while loop iteration (one epoch of sensor threads).

I manage to do it with an atomic where the third thread is only checking the requests when the atomic flag has been raised. However, the numbers that I am getting after that seams not reliable.

2. In the case where one of the first threads can fail and not send a reliable flag. What mechanism you would use to signal the third thread that execution is done and that it should check incoming requests?

Do you have any idea why this kind of problem would occur? Could one of the problems be `chono` epoch time derivation?

**Sensor threads**

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <chrono>
#include <vector>
#include <atomic>
#include <mutex>
#include <random>

#include "control_thread.h"

#define INTERNAL_THREAD 

#if defined INTERNAL_THREAD
#include <thread>
#include <pthread.h>
#else
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#endif

using namespace std;



static long global_time_stamp;

atomic<bool> thread_active[2];
atomic<bool> go;

template <typename T> 
void propose(Message volatile * m, unsigned int epoch, T val, bool flag) {
  for (int i = 0 ; i < sizeof(T); i++){
    m->buffer[i] = val;
    m->epoch = epoch;
    m->flag = flag;
  }
}


ControlThread * ct;

// Main run for threads
void run(unsigned int threadID, unsigned long f, unsigned long n){

    // Put message into incoming buffer
    Message volatile * m1 = &(ct->incoming[threadID - 1]);

    printf(BLUE("Thread %ld (of %ld) is here, working with f = %ld\n"), threadID, n, f);

    thread_active[threadID] = true;

    thread_local long loc_epoch;
    thread_local int loc_Ti = 3;

    thread_local int current_position;
    thread_local int random;

    std::atomic<bool> loc_flag;

    // this thread is done initializing stuff 
    thread_active[threadID] = true;

    while (!go);

    while(true){

        long current_time = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(std::chrono::time_point_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(std::chrono::steady_clock::now()).time_since_epoch()).count();


        loc_epoch = (current_time - global_time_stamp) / loc_Ti;

        // This value should comes from sensor
        // random = intRand(5,15);

        // Code for preforming operations on sensors

        // Proposing request to the third thread
        loc_flag = true;
        propose<int>(m1, loc_epoch, random, loc_flag);

        current_position = current_time % loc_Ti;

        auto current_position_millis = chrono::milliseconds(current_position);

        std::chrono::duration<double, milli> multi_thread_sleep = chrono::milliseconds(loc_Ti) - current_position_millis;

        if(multi_thread_sleep > chrono::milliseconds::zero()){
          this_thread::sleep_for(multi_thread_sleep);
        }

    }

}

template <typename T>
void propose_time(TimePassing volatile * tp, int start_time){
  tp->start = start_time;
}


void server(unsigned long f, unsigned long n) {
      printf ("server here: %ld %ld\n", f, n);
        
      for (int i=1; i < n+1; i++){
        while (!thread_active[i]);
      }
    
      // initialize time
      global_time_stamp = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(std::chrono::time_point_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(std::chrono::steady_clock::now()).time_since_epoch()).count();
      TimePassing volatile * tp = &(ct->global_start_time);
    
      propose_time<long>(tp, global_time_stamp);
    
      go = true;
    
      while (go) {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
          ct->check_incoming_request(i);
        }
      }
    }
    
    class Thread {
    
    public:
    #if defined INTERNAL_THREAD
      thread execution_handle;
    #endif
    
      unsigned int id; 
      
      Thread(unsigned int i) : id(i) {}
    
    };
    
    
    void init(unsigned long f, unsigned long n) {
      ct = new ControlThread(f, n);
    }
    
    
    int main (int argc, char * argv[]) {
    
      Thread * r[4];
    
      if (argc < 2) {
        printf("usage n number of healty threads f - number of faulty threads\n");
        return 0;
      }
    
      char * end;
      unsigned long n = strtoul(argv[1], &end, 10);
      unsigned long f = strtoul(argv[2], &end, 10);
    
      init(f, n);
    
      /* start threads
       *================*/
    
      for (unsigned int i = 0; i < n + 1; i++) {
        r[i] = new Thread(i);
      
    #if defined INTERNAL_THREAD
        if(i==0){
          r[0]->execution_handle = std::thread([f,n] {server(f,n);});
        }else if(i == 1){
          r[i]->execution_handle = std::thread([i,f,n] {run(i,f,n);});
        }else if(i == 2){
          r[i]->execution_handle = std::thread([i,f,n] {run(i,f,n);});
        }
    
        /* pin to core i */
        cpu_set_t cpuset;
        CPU_ZERO(&cpuset);
        CPU_SET(i, &cpuset);
        int rc = pthread_setaffinity_np(r[i]->execution_handle.native_handle(), sizeof(cpuset), &cpuset);
    
    
    #endif
      }
    // wait for threads to end
    
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < n + 1; i++) {
      #if defined INTERNAL_THREAD    
        r[i]->execution_handle.join();
      #endif
      }
    
      return 0;
    }
```

**Control Thread**

```
#ifndef __CONTROL_THEAD_H__
#define __CONTROL_THEAD_H__

#define RED(x)    "\e[1;31m" x "\e[0m"
#define BLUE(x)   "\e[1;34m" x "\e[0m"


class TimePassing{
  public:
  long start;

};


class Message{
public:
  // write size bytes from buffer to dest
  unsigned int  buffer[64];  
  std::atomic<bool> flag;

  unsigned long epoch;
};



class ControlThread {
public:

  /* rw individual threads */
  Message volatile incoming[4];

  TimePassing volatile global_start_time;

  unsigned long contol_thread_epoch;

  unsigned long f;
  unsigned long n;


  ControlThread(unsigned long f, unsigned long n) : f(f), n(n), contol_thread_epoch(0) {
    for (int i = 1; i < 3; i++) {
      incoming[i].flag = true;
    }
  }

  int Ti = 3;

  void check_incoming_request(unsigned long current_thread) {

    long current_time = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>
    (std::chrono::time_point_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>
    (std::chrono::steady_clock::now()).time_since_epoch()).count();

    contol_thread_epoch = (current_time - global_start_time.start) / Ti;

      // Only check request when flag is raised
      if(incoming[current_thread].flag){

        incoming[current_thread].flag = false;

        // You can only go when flag is set
        // All the incoming flags should be 0. Why they are not?
        printf("Request: %ld %d %d\n", current_thread, unsigned(incoming[current_thread].flag), contol_thread_epoch);

        // If sensor thread epoch and control thread matches
        if(incoming[current_thread].epoch == contol_thread_epoch){

          // printf("You are at the right epoch \n");

        }else{
          printf(RED("Wrong epoch %d %d %d\n"), incoming[current_thread].epoch, incoming[current_thread].epoch, contol_thread_epoch);
        }
      }
    }
  };
#endif
```

**Command**

```
g++ -std=c++2a -pthread -lrt -lm -lcrypt your_file.cc -o file
# Number of healty and faulty threads
sudo ./file 2 0
```

These are the results. The first is thread ID followed by the output of the flag. It should be always 0 but it is somehow not set properly in certain cases. The last number is current request number

```
Request: 0 0 227 // Good epoch
Request: 1 0 227
Request: 0 0 228
Request: 1 0 228
Request: 0 0 229
Request: 1 0 229
Request: 0 1 230 // Faulty epoch
Request: 1 0 230
Request: 0 0 230 // It propagates
Request: 0 0 231
Request: 1 0 231
Request: 0 0 231
Wrong epoch 232 232 231 // Control and sensor threads out of sync
Request: 1 0 232
Request: 1 1 233
Request: 0 0 233
```

Comment: What use is a thread_local atomic? Are the sensor threads able to tell that they failed btw? [`std::barrier`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/barrier) may work for you assuming you've got a compiler with C++ 20 support available

Comment: Leaving `thread_local` together with atomics was a mistake. I edited the post. The results remained the same. Only one sensor thread can fail at a particular epoch (one loop iteration), and if it fails, it cannot send a proper request, so only the third thread should check if that thread has failed. I will check for the `std::barrier` I wasn't aware of this mechanism

Comment: Please first extract a [mcve], both for demonstation here, but also so that you extract the core of the problem. The code you provide isn't even formatted consistently! As a new user here, please also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: @fabian A thread_local atomic would be useful if you passed its address to another thread. Not very useful otherwise.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @UlrichEckhardt. I updated the post accordingly so the reproducible test example is available.

Comment: This code is very hard to understand. Why is `loc_flag` atomic? Why so many thread local variables that are already function local?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz So many `thread_local` because the value that needs to be proposed to the control thread coming from sensors needs to be deterministic. Meaning that both threads should come to the same conclusion after operating on the value from sensors. Currently, `loc_flag` is not part of that design. Still, changing the flag to `thread_local` doesn't affect results.

Comment: There are still two files (incomplete, without `#includes`), some conditional code, some seemingly unused code (look at `loc_flag`). All this doesn't help. Also, I don't understand your use of thread-local vars. They don't magically make things "deterministic". Why not just use a function-local variable? Maybe you could also explain what observations you made that prompted you to make them thread-local.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I added the missing `#includes` in the file. `loc_flag` is not left unused as this is a flag set when the request from sensor threads is ready for proposing to the control thread. I am aware that thread-local vars are not making things deterministic, but for simplicity, I didn't want to describe a mechanism that ensures that. The issue is not because of thread determinism, but as the title says, the synchronization between threads, so the accurate epoch that the threads should be in subsequent epochs, but they are failing to do so as seen in results.

Comment: How is `loc_flag` set? It is function-local, it is only repeatedly set to the same constant value and then its boolean value is passed to a function. That said, I'm voting to close this question for now, because there is still no [mcve] and it's (partially due to this lack) unclear what your actual problem is.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt `loc_flag` is set on the sensor threads but then released in the control thread. By the code `incoming[current_thread].flag = false`, so I am not following how this var is not used. Regarding the minimal reproducible example, I am sure you can now get the same results if you use the provided code. I think the problem is clear. I always want to satisfy the following timing condition in the control thread `if(incoming[current_thread].epoch == contol_thread_epoch)`. Anyways, thanks for your help

Comment: Please search for "loc_flag" in this SO question. It is only used inside of a single function of your code and in the comments. Just for safety: A function-local variable is unique for every call to that function. Different calls (including recursive one or from multiple threads) don't share any local variable, unless it is declared `static`.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Even do you are completely right that the design of the thread_local variable setting is not respected in some cases, that's not the problem here. You can declare the same vars as just local, and the same behavior will be present. The issue is with timing and synchronization between threads